# Compose navigation is experiencing significant glitches during navigation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple application where I implemented 2 screens with lists. When navigating to a screen, I call LaunchedEffect, which fetches data from the network. I built navigation following the example of the now in android project. My lists look pretty simple, but the navigation behaves poorly.

On my phone with 120 Hz, the fps drops to 10 frames, giving the impression that the application is freezing during simple actions.

Here's my code

```
@Composable
fun TabsTwoScreen(
    tabsTwoViewModel: TabsTwoViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    var comments by tabsTwoViewModel.comments

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        delay(300)
        tabsTwoViewModel.getComments()
    })

    when (comments) {
        is NetworkResponse.Loading -> {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(1f)) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        }

        is NetworkResponse.Success -> {
            (comments as NetworkResponse.Success<List<PostCommentsItem>>).data?.let { data ->

                LazyColumn(
                    content = {

                        items(data,
                            key = { data -> data.id }
                        ) {
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .background(Color(0xFFB6B6B6))
                                    .height(150.dp),
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.Top)
                            ) {

                                Row {
                                    Icon(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_ios_24),
                                        contentDescription = ""
                                    )
                                    Icon(...)
                                }

                                Row {

                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.test_image),
                                        contentDescription = "",
                                        modifier = Modifier.size(90.dp)
                                    )

                                    Column {
                                        
                                        Text(
                                            text = "# ${it.id}",
                                            fontSize = 22.sp,
                                            color = Color(0xFFFF6D00)
                                        )
                                        Text(...)
                                        Text(...)
                                        Text(...)
                                    }
                                }

                                Row {
                                    TextButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                                        Text("button")
                                    }
                                    TextButton(...}
                                    TextButton(...}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp, Alignment.Top),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TabsTwoViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val serviceApi: ServiceApi,
) : ViewModel() {

    var comments = mutableStateOf<NetworkResponse<List<PostCommentsItem>>?>(null)
        private set

    fun getComments(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val list = ArrayList<PostCommentsItem>()
                serviceApi.postsComments().also { res->
                    if(res is NetworkResponse.Success){
                        res.data?.forEachIndexed { index, postCommentsItem ->
                            list.add(postCommentsItem)
                        }
                    }
                }
            comments.value = NetworkResponse.Success(data = list)
        }
    }
}
```

The first screen looks the same as `TabsTwoScreen`

Please take a look at the video where I added an fps counter in the bottom right corner.

Use libs:

```
compose_navigation = '2.7.5'
compose_ui_version = '1.5.4'
compose_compiler_version = '1.5.5'
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

I've tried to find similar issues on the internet, but the advice I found didn't help me.